# How to refer filling of one form with the filling of other in Atk4

Tags: atk4

I have made two forms for logged users. The first one is for trip info (name, short description) and the second is for different landmarks (name, description) that are part of the trip of current user. Is it possible to "connect" the user with filling of trip form and the form for landmarks that is going to be used several times for different landmarks. I have the models "trips", "user" and "landmarks" with respective id's, but I can not solve the problem alone.

........................

I have tried this and it happened (thanks to Romaninsh):

```
function page_trips(){
$this->api->stickyGET('id');
$id=$this->api->auth->get('id');
$f=$this->add('Form');
$f->addField('line','name')->setNotNULL();
$f->addField('Text','short_desc')->setNotNULL();
$f->setSource('trips');
$f->setConditionFromGET();
$f->dq
     ->set('user_id',$id);
$f->addSubmit('Next');
if($f->isSubmitted())
{
    $f->update();

    $f->js()->univ()->location($this->api->getDestinationUrl('../targets')
    )

    ->execute();
}
}
```

Now I can enter an info about new trip and save to table with respective user id. The rest of the task is to add different landmarks to current trip.

Comment: Are you looking to populate user_id of your "Trip" model with the currently logged-in user when he's filling out the form?

Comment: Yes. This is the first problem for me. The second is when the user finishes with the trip form he have to fill and form for landmarks that must be refered to the trip and user.

Comment: It looks like api->stickyGET() and model->setMasterField() is what's needed. It will allow you to pass hidden arguments through pages and set default values for certain model fields.

Comment: Do you have a page to enter the trips and a separate page to enter the itinerary or do you want to have these on the same page ?

Comment: I have a page called "addtrips". I want to enter the info about the trip and itinerary at that page.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's what you are looking as i used a two page design and you would probably use another one to add/edit/delete landmarks but maybe this will give you some ideas.

I created a three tables in the database - trip, landmark and landmarktrip with the following definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `landmark` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `landmark` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Xintiandi'),
(2, 'Pearl TV Tower'),
(3, 'YuYuan Gardens'),
(4, 'Shanghai Botanical Gardens'),
(5, 'Shanghai World Financial Centre');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `landmarktrip` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trip_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `landmark_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `landmarktrip` (`id`, `trip_id`, `landmark_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 2, 3),
(5, 2, 4),
(6, 1, 5);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trip` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `short_desc` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='7741244' AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `trip` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`, `short_desc`, `start_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Shanghai 1', 'First Trip To China', '2011-10-13'),
(2, 1, 'Shanghai 2', 'Return Visit', '2011-10-21');
```

And then created models in wwwroot/website/lib/Model as follows

**Landmark.php**

```
class Model_Landmark extends Model_Table {
   public $entity_code='landmark';
   public $table_alias='l';

   function init(){ 
     parent::init();
     $this->addField('id')->mandatory(true)->system(true)->visible(false);
     $this->addField('name')->mandatory(true);
   }
}
```

**Trip.php**

```
class Model_Trip extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='trip';
    public $table_alias='t';

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('id')->mandatory(true)->system(true)->visible(false);


 $this->addField('user_id')->defaultValue($this->api->auth->get('id'))->visible(false);
        $this->addField('name')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('short_desc')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('start_date')->dataType('date')->mandatory(true);
    }
  } 
}
```

**LandmarkTrip.php**

```
class Model_LandmarkTrip extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='landmarktrip';
    public $table_alias='lt';

  function init(){
       parent::init();
       $this->addField('id')->system(true)->visible(false);  
           $this->addField('trip_id')->refModel('Model_Trip')->mandatory(true);
       $this->addField('landmark_id')->refModel('Model_Landmark')->mandatory(true);
  }
}
```

Created two pages in wwwroot/website/page, one to add the trips and one for the itinerary as i dont see how with the form approach you are using, you can select which trip you want to see the details of.

**trips.php**

```
class page_trips extends page {
 function init() {
   parent::init();
   $p=$this;

   $c=$p->add('CRUD')->setModel('Trip');
   $c->setMasterField('user_id', $this->api->auth->get('id'));

  }
}
```

**itinerary.php**

```
class page_itinerary extends page {

  function init() {
    parent::init();
    $p=$this;

    $this->js()->_load('trip_univ');

    $triplist=$this->api->db->dsql()->table('trip t')
              ->field('t.id')
              ->field('t.name')
              ->where('t.user_id', $p->api->auth->get('id'))
              ->order('t.start_date')
              ->do_getAssoc();


    if ($_GET['trip']){
          $curr_trip=$_GET['trip'];
    } else {
          $earliest=$this->api->db->dsql()->table('trip')
                   ->field('min(start_date)')
                   ->where('user_id',$this->api->auth->get('id'))
                   ->do_getOne();

          $curr_trip=$this->api->db->dsql()->table('trip')
                   ->field('id')
                   ->where('user_id',$this->api->auth->get('id'))
                   ->where('start_date',$earliest)
                   ->do_getOne();
    }

    $f=$p->add('Form')->setFormClass('horizontal');
    $list=$f->addField('dropdown','trip')->setValueList($triplist)->set($curr_trip);
    $list->js('change')->univ()->viewTrip($p->api->getDestinationURL(null), $list);


    $lt=$p->add('CRUD')->setModel('LandmarkTrip');
    $lt->setMasterField('trip_id', $curr_trip);

  }
}
```

and one last file which allows the list to change the grid
Create a file called trips_univ.js in wwwroot/website/templates/js

**trip_univ.js**

```
$.each({
    viewTrip: function(url, name){
              document.location.href=url+'&trip='+$(name).val();
    }
},$.univ._import);
```

So now, you can create trips using the CRUD to add, edit and delete rows.
Then go to the itinerary page to select a trip from the dropdown list or it defaults to the earliest trip and can add, remove or edit landmarks from the trip.

Comment: Thanks. It could be improved by adding a getDefaultTrip function to the user model as you suggested and setting this instead of selecting in the page but it's very similar to the pages i've developed for the scrumwall.

Comment: No problem - if it's the right answer, dont forget to mark the tick next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have solved your problem partially, I just need to add some notes on how to incorporate multiple actions into the form.

```
$form->setModel('Trip');
$form->addField('line','extrainfo'):

if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $form->update();

    $it=$this->add('Model_Itinerary');
    $it->set('trip_id', $form->getModel()->get('id'));
    $it->set('extrainfo', $form->get('extrainfo'));
    $it->update();
}
```

This way you can create multiple models when the form is saved.

Comment: Is there a way to step through several records with a form If the model has several rows returned ? Eg moving forward and backward through the recordset ?

Comment: Uhm, no standard form wouldn't support it, but I don't think it's too complex to implement.

Comment: True just wanted to check it's not part of the default - i think a basic master detail screen would be a nice inclusion besides the CRUD - will probably develop one in due course (if noone else does it first) and add it to github.

Comment: Is there a fast way to take the last id of current SQL table in Atk4?

Comment: Do you mean between pages, how do you define the last id and how do you define which table that id is for ? You can use some functions to store session variables e.g. $this->memorize('trip',$current_trip) and $this->recall('trip') and $this->forget('trip'). You can also use $this->api->memorize('trip',$trip).

Comment: You should ideally ask a separate question on stackoverflow as it makes it easier for others to find the answers when they are looking in the future. Thanks.

Comment: You can also add public variables to the model so you could include functions in the model to get and set the variable and then store it as part of the page processing. Not sure what the intention is so difficult to recommend the solution (but ask a separate question)

Comment: after $model->update() you can check $model->get('id'). The only catch here if you gave conditions on model which will prevent record from loading, you won't get ID. That's a good indication that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I am trying to test another way for my case. When the trips form is filled and submitted there are a new record in 'trips' table in the database with new id (last id). I want to take this id and store it with landmarks form when it is submitted

Comment: I think then store it in a session variable with memorize and recall it in the other page - but what if a trip is created previously and you want to add landmarks to it ? Then the session variable is empty hence why i used a dropdown list in my example.

Comment: Hi Trevor, I want to try a way in wich I add the information for a new trip step by step. I mean at the first page I enter info for the trip using form and after that when it is submitted I can enter info for a landmark in a new form. Your suggestion is excellent for editting old trips and landmarks. Thank you for your worth advices.

Comment: if you want to split process into multiple steps, here is a sample: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/newsletter